# Why when I change copy of object in TS, original one also changes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm importing redux store and using the spread operator to create a copy of store property. Then when I change this copy, the original property also changes.

When I use `copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original))` everything works fine.

```
export const move = (moveData: IMove): BoardActionTypes => {
  const { board } = store.getState();
  console.log(board.pieces.byId["19"]); // {row: 3, col: 7}

  const newById: IPiecesById = { ...board.pieces.byId };

  newById["19"].col = 4;
  newById["19"].row = 4;

  console.log(board.pieces.byId["19"]); // {row: 4, col: 4}
  console.log(newById["19"]); // {row: 4, col: 4}

  //...
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is about shallow VS deep copy of an object.

When using spread operator, your creating a shallow copy of an object (Just like when using old-school [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)).

When you've used JSON parsing - you get a deep copy (or a "deep clone") of the object.

Shallow copy, as the name suggest, means that the outer object is a new one, while nested objects remains the same. Once you get to know redux in-depth, speard operators should be suffice for most cases, but it is an important difference to keep in mind.

You might want to read [my question on this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025555/redux-why-using-object-assign-if-it-is-not-perform-deep-clone), and [this article](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab) as well,.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 options for it.

**1. Using `underscore.js`**

```js
var foo = { row: 0, col:0 };
var bar = _.clone(foo);
bar.row = 99;

console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore.js"></script>
```

**2. vanilla JS**

```js
function clone(obj) {
  if (obj === null || typeof(obj) !== 'object')
  return obj;

  var copy = obj.constructor();

  for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
  }

  return copy;
}

var foo = { row: 0, col: 0 };
var bar = clone(foo);
bar.row = 99;

console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens to you is - two objects with the same reference.

If you don't want to use an external lib, or a helper function (if you're not going to use it extensively), you can use something like this:

```
const newById = board.pieces.byId.map((item) => ({ ...item }));
```

(i assumed byId is an array, and map creates new array)