# how to update array object within the componentDidUpdate method

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch the new updated state object within componentDidUpdate method. but its returning the the old values in the array.

A user enters a image title, and uploads an image, and react should `console.log` a new array object with the new values. Without having to refresh.

For example the following array should have two keys along with values within the array considering i just added an image **without refreshing**.

[image]

and on refresh, the array is updated

[image]

> dashboard.js 66

this is `console.log(prevState.images)`

```
[
  {
    "id": 139,
    "image_title": "owl",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559966278/uploads/wph0kuhzg52lxkhxmxsi.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T03:57:58.351Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T03:57:58.351Z",
    "user_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 138,
    "image_title": "uuuuuu",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559965905/uploads/m1oxtyae2d6pyvteidyq.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T03:51:46.815Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T03:51:46.815Z",
    "user_id": null
  }
]
```

Ideally a new object array with the new values should append the array without having to refresh the page.

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import Image from './Image';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            image_url: 'http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg', 
            images: [], 
            description:'',
            upload:false,
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        // console.log(this.state.description)
        // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                image_url:response.data.img_url,
                description:response.data.image_title
                // images: [...this.state.images, this.state.image_url ]
            })
        });
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
        // console.log(this.state.description)
    }
    fileOnchange = (file) => {
        this.setState({
            [file[0].target.name]: file[0].target.value
        })
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
            // let img;
            // let imgTitle;
            Object.keys(response.data).forEach( (key) => {
                // console.log(response.data);
                // img = response.data[key].img_url
                // imgTitle = response.data[key].image_title
                // pulling in the data from the backend
                console.log(response.data[key]);
                this.setState({
                    images:[ ...this.state.images, response.data[key]]
                })
                console.log(this.state.images);
            });
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.image_url !== prevState.image_url) {
            // trying to fetch the new upated array. but not sure how. 
            console.log(prevState.images);
            this.setState({
                images: [this.state.image_url, this.state.description, ...this.state.images]
            });
        }
      }
    onUploadClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            upload: !this.state.upload
        })
    }
    render(){
        const uploader = ( 
            <ImageUploader
                withIcon={true}
                withPreview={true}
                onChange={this.handleUpload}
                singleImage={true}
                buttonText='Upload an image'
                imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                maxFileSize={5242880}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} md={6} style={{ margin: '40px 0px', padding: '0px 30px'}}>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Welcome to the Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                        <Button onClick={this.onUploadClick} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                            {/* toggle between Upload or Close
                                Will be upload by default, else if upload is clicked, close will show.
                            */}
                            {!this.state.upload ? "Upload": "Close"}
                        </Button>
                        {this.state.upload ? (
                            <div>
                             <TextField
                                 id="outlined-name"
                                 label="Image Title"
                                 name="description"
                                 type="text"
                                 fullWidth
                                 style={{ borderRadius: '0px'}}
                                 className=""
                                 value={this.state.description}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 margin="normal"
                               />
                                <br></br>
                                <br></br>
                              {uploader}
                            </div>
                        ):(
                            null
                        )}
                    {this.state.images.length > 0 ? (
                        this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
                            <Grid item sm={12} md={12} key={i} style={{ margin: '30px 0px'}}>
                                 <Paper>
                                        {/* // empty image_title */}
                                     <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.image_title}</Typography> 
                                    <Image image_url={img.img_url} />    
                                </Paper>                              
                            </Grid>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Grid item md={8}>
                                <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Grid>
                {/* Images  */}
              </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

**componentDidUpdate**

`console.log(this.state.images);`

The values are passed, but not the way i would like

[image]

The last two values are not within the nested array. as the rest as the others.

```
[
  {
    "id": 142,
    "image_title": "cheese",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559973164/uploads/bvfotlfivr4yqsqhkvrw.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T05:52:45.203Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T05:52:45.203Z",
    "user_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 141,
    "image_title": "owl",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559972965/uploads/w9aup9r76q6hiktdjvyp.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T05:49:26.911Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T05:49:26.911Z",
    "user_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 140,
    "image_title": "tea",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559966806/uploads/y9q4upguo3hy6vhkk0va.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T04:06:47.217Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T04:06:47.217Z",
    "user_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 139,
    "image_title": "owl",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559966278/uploads/wph0kuhzg52lxkhxmxsi.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T03:57:58.351Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T03:57:58.351Z",
    "user_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 138,
    "image_title": "uuuuuu",
    "img_url": "http://res.cloudinary.com/dq281hpqd/image/upload/v1559965905/uploads/m1oxtyae2d6pyvteidyq.png",
    "created_at": "2019-06-08T03:51:46.815Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-08T03:51:46.815Z",
    "user_id": null
  },
  "http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg",
  "cheese2"
]
```

Comment: Why do you `this.props.history.push("/dashboard")` in `handleUpload()` when you are already in the Dashboard route?

Comment: yeah its not working, it should refresh the page..  but its not working. I will fix later.

Comment: Gotcha. Also, its unclear what you are trying to accomplish in componentDidUpdate(), you are already adding the image through handleUpload. And now you are trying to add an additional image in componentDidUpdate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute `handleUpload()` it looks like you just are not passing the new image object correctly to your component-state, I'll break this down into parts:

### This is fine:

```
handleUpload =  file =>  {
    const data = new FormData()
    const image = file[0]
    data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
    Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
```

### Create a shallow copy of the new image:

This is good practice so you do not accidentally mutate the original object. *Although to be honest we probably do not need to do this because the item is stored in your database and any mutations here would not affect it*

```
    const newImage = {...response.data}
```

We want a new object that contains all key-value pairs of the old object. Since the image object only has one layer of data `{ key: string }` not `{ key: {} }` using the spread operator `...` is sufficient.

We do this because we never want to run into a scenario like this:

```
const newImage = response.data // { url: "https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/funny-cat.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782"}

newImage.url = "https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/scared-surprised-cat-face.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782"
```

Our expectation is that our code will only change the url in newImage, but we will find that response.data also been changed:

```
console.log(newImage.url) //"https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/scared-surprised-cat-face.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782"
console.log(response.data.url)  //"https://boygeniusreport.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/scared-surprised-cat-face.jpg?quality=98&strip=all&w=782"
```

In JavaScript, when you make a copy of an object, `const newImage = oldImage` you do not just simply copy its value. You copy its **entire reference** in memory. Making a shallow-copy with `...` works around that by making a completely new reference. It's good practice to make a **shallow-copy** if you ever want to define new values inside an object you initially copied.

### Update component-state

```
        this.setState({
            image_url: newImage.img_url,
            description: newImage.image_title,
            images: [
               ...this.state.images,
               {
                  id: newImage.id,
                  image_title: newImage.image_title,
                  img_url: newImage.img_url,
                  created_at: newImage.created_at,
                  updated_at: newImage.updated_at,
                  user_id: null
               }
            ]
        })

    });
}
```

This code-block here says we will make a shallow-copy of `this.state.images`, Then we will create a new object, using the values inside our `newImage` obj. As you remember, `newImage` was made by creating a shallow-copy of response.data. So newImage has all the key-value pairs we need.

```
images: [
   ...this.state.images,
   {
      id: newImage.id,
      image_title: newImage.image_title,
      img_url: newImage.img_url,
      created_at: newImage.created_at,
      updated_at: newImage.updated_at,
      user_id: null
   }
]
```

Also, when you call `componentDidUpdate()` you are adding only **description** and **image_url** as individual values to the images array. This seems like a mistake, you already added the image in your `handleClick()`. But, if really want tom you should pass in an object if anything like so.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.state.images.length !== prevState.images.length){
       //unnecessary, since we already added the image, but test it out anyway.
       this.setState({
           images: [...this.state.images, { image_url: this.state.image_url, description: this.state.description}]
       })
    }
}
```

Note: If you decide to use `componentDidUpdate()` you'll notice that you will not have fields like `"created_at", "updated_at"` and others available because those are fields added to the new image object from your backend API.

Comment: For sure, let me know :)

Comment: oh yeah their is a miss understanding, will update the code. to show you the console.log

Comment: just updated the code. Hopefully you have an idea what i wanted  to achieve, thanks.

Comment: so ideally the two values should be appended in the array. and then componentDidUpdate should fetch the new array. with the new values. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @randal oh that's what you mean haha

Comment: about to try this out, sorry for delay will let you know how it went.

Comment: it's working perfectly, Thanks a ton. Where would i get more information on shallow copying and stuff in react ?

Comment: I do have one more request, if you can edit the code by adding comments to explain the steps you are doing. I want to be able to understand this better. i learn best by step by step comment code. Mainly your reasons for doing  `const newImage = {...response.data} `

Comment: @randal. Of course. Let me reference you my favorite answer about shallow-copying. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025555/redux-why-using-object-assign-if-it-is-not-perform-deep-clone. Ill comment my code too.