# What does a state mean in Angular application?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am new to NgRx and going through its documentation. But, at the beginning, I'm encountered with the following sentence:

> State is a single, immutable data structure.

What does the state mean in simple words? Need some simple examples to understand this concept.

Do I need to learn Flux and Redux to understand these concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, a state in ngrx (or redux, or other state managment systems) is how your system is described in a single point in time.

You can think about it as a plain javascript object that represent your entire application at one point. Let's take a simple example of a `todo`s app, where i can mark a completed item (by a completed flag) or selected item (by index). a possible state might look like this:

```
{
  items: [
    { text: 'Wash Car', completed: false},
    { text: 'Write Code', completed: true}
  ],
  selectedIndex: 0
}
```

If I'll decide to select the second index, my state future state would look like this:

```
{
  items: [
    { text: 'Wash Car', completed: false},
    { text: 'Write Code', completed: true}
  ],
  selectedIndex: 1
}
```

So, a state is a representation of your app logic in a single point of time. The view implementation is up to you - angular, react, and mobile application can share the same state and use different view layer.

Some state-management system require the state to be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), meaning that in the `todos` example **I wouldn't simply change my state, but rather create an entire new state to represent the change in the system.**

There are [multiple reasons](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data#benefits-of-immutability) for that, but maybe the most obvious one is that this quality help web systems to recognize changes in the state, and change the view accordingly.

NgRx is an angular-specific state management system. as described in [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) page:

> NgRx Store provides reactive state management for Angular apps inspired by Redux.

So, a good point to state would be to learn redux (The rule of immutability comes from redux). You can look at NgRx as a redux-based state management, power with RxJS. I would suggest to learn each concept desperately and then move to learn NgRx.

Update: These questions might be useful

1. [Why should objects in Redux be immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958775/why-should-objects-in-redux-be-immutable)
2. [Redux: why using Object.assign if it is not perform deep clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025555/redux-why-using-object-assign-if-it-is-not-perform-deep-clone)

Comment: Thanks! This will help me to get off the ground in NgRx.