# Store object size on react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Is any performance issue with put many items in `redux-store`?
for example, the store is like this:

```
{
    user:{...},
    userDetail:{},
    shoppingCart:{},
    OrderDetail:{},
    ...
}
```

Its keys count is almost 50 items.

I'm using `react-redux` in my project to store any data (even data that are used in one section of my app and are not share).

Comment: Performance-wise, it really depends by how much each element grows in size. I would rather create several stores to keep the code clean. E.g. a store for the cart, a store for the user and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the size of your data, and the way you use it.

**data size**

You've said you have around 50 items. does each item is an object? does it have 20 properties? maybe 20,000 properties?
I've used redux with around 10,000 complex items (20-30 properties each) and did not experience issues, but your data / behavior might be very different

**data usage**

How do you treat each change? Is the effect cause a minor change, or do you change the DOM significantly? do you use redux [selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)?

Remember that when it comes to performance, Rendering is usually much more costly than updating a data object (even a large one like redux store), so for more cases **it's not your state management, it's how you use it**.

However, that does not mean you may not encounter problems, so the best way to approach it would be to actually **test the problematic scenarios**, probably with a [benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) [test](https://github.com/bestiejs/benchmark.js).

Generally speaking, redux considerated to be a highly-performant state-management system, considering you use it properly:

Use selectors when required, write proper reducers and splitting ui & data effectively to reducers etc.

Comment: So you mean there is not any difference in **performance** between using state or global store?

Comment: What do you mean by `global store`?

Comment: I say that it's probably not about redux, which have great performance, it's about how you use it, and what cause elements to render

Comment: when I say `global store` i mean `redux store`;

Comment: my concern is that when importing redux and saga in my project and use it to manage store it cause performance issue because it is not like state;

Comment: I think the `state` is faster than `redux-store`, isn't it?

Comment: You're comment suggets that you might have a confusion about these terms.

A *store* in redux, is a structure which hold your basic redux functions, like *getState* and *dispatch*.

A *state* is an object which represent your application at a specific point in time.

So, in redux, a state is part of your store. or more accurately, a store is a container for your state (among other things)

Comment: Maybe this will clarify some things for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747624/what-does-a-state-mean-in-angular-application/56749118#56749118